# Decoding AAC in FFmpeg for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, decoding, aac

I am attempting to decode an M4A file on an Android device using AAC.

I use the following code to initialize the codec.

```
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_AAC);
c= avcodec_alloc_context();
avcodec_open(c, codec);
```

However, when I later attempt to decode a frame using:

```
len = avcodec_decode_audio3(c, (short *)mOutbuf, &out_size, &avpkt);
```

I get -1 (indicating an error) and the following on the log.

```
10-11 16:30:01.115: INFO/M4ADecoder(5260): channel element 0.0 is not allocated
10-11 16:30:02.195: INFO/M4ADecoder(5260): channel element 2.0 is not allocated
10-11 16:30:03.295: INFO/M4ADecoder(5260): channel element 0.6 is not allocated
10-11 16:30:07.645: INFO/M4ADecoder(5260): Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
10-11 16:30:07.655: INFO/M4ADecoder(5260): Number of bands (3) exceeds limit (2).
```

Are there any other steps I need to do when setting up the codec?  Do I need to preparse the file before sending data to the AAC decoder?

The same file works fine with the latest ffmpeg code on Mac OSX (i.e., ffmpeg -i filename.m4a").

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I ahve the same probelm decoding AAC - "channel element not supported"